How to hide/remove file bowser context menu items and disable some commands in jupyter lab custom extension?
I tried to modify the existing context menu in the following way and the item length is always zero which means menu items are empty in my custom extension.
const { contextMenu } = app;
      const itemsToRemove = ['file browser:cut', 'file browser:paste', 'file browser:copy'];
      itemsToRemove.forEach(item => {
        contextMenu.menu.items.forEach(mItem => {
            contextMenu.menu.removeItitemtem);
            //contextMenu.menu.removeItemAt(0);
        });
      And;

and for removing existing commands by following code and its not working because it gives an error that the command is already registered.
//Function to disable a command
const disableCommand = (commandId: string) => {
      commands.addCommand(commandId, {
        execute: () => {
          console.log(`${commandId} is disabled`);
        },
        isEnabled: () => false
      });
      commands.notifyCommandChanged(commandId);
    };

    //Listen for command executions
    commands.commandExecuted.connect((sender, args) => {
      if (args.id === 'apputils:activate-command-palette') {
        disableCommand(args.id);
      }
    });

how to fix these issues in jupyter lab 4.2.5 version
